# std::enable_if for template method defined in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, enable-if

I work on a templated class whose method definitions are in the cpp file. Now I would like to add another method which will be enabled for certain class template parameter only. My current approach:

#### .h

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
   template <typename U = T,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<SpecialType, U>::value>::type* = 0>
   T& Foo();
}
```

#### .cpp

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<SpecialType, U>::value>::type*>
T& MyClass<T>::Foo()
{
   // Implementation...
}

// Exported explicit instantiations
template class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass<SpecialType>;
template class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass<OtherType>;
...
```

This compiles just fine in both the implementation cpp and sites which include the header. The problem is with linker where I get unresolved external symbol.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
   "public: class SpecialType & __cdecl MyClass<class SpecialType>::Foo<class SpecialType,0>(void)" 
   (??$Foo@VSpecialType@@$0A@@?$MyClass@VSpecialType@@@@QEAAAEAVSpecialType@@XZ) referenced in function MyFunction
```

What is the problem?
Btw: other non-enable_if methods link well.

Comment: `template <typename X> template <typename Y>` != `template <typename X, typename Y>`

Comment: In other words, when you have a template function inside a template class, the implementation requires two separate `template` specifications (one for the containing class, one for the function).

Comment: Try something as `template <typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<SpecialType, U>::value>::type>
   T& Foo()`; I mean: the test has to be about a template parameter of the method itself (`U`), not about a template parameter of the class (`T`).

Comment: 0x5453, @max66, I followed your ideas and updated the question to my current state.

Comment: Now the question is completely different. You should, IMHO, close this question and open another question.

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare `Foo` it would need to be called like `Foo<>()`, which is less than ideal.

---

> Now I would like to add another method which will be enabled for certain class template parameter only.

An alternative way to achieve that is to specialize a (derived) part of the class for `SpecialType`:

```
struct SpecialType;

template<typename T>
struct MyClassCommon {};

// Generic version.
template<typename T>
struct MyClass : MyClassCommon<T> {
    using MyClassCommon<T>::MyClassCommon;
};

// Specialization for SpecialType.
template<>
struct MyClass<SpecialType> : MyClassCommon<SpecialType> {
    using MyClassCommon<SpecialType>::MyClassCommon;
    SpecialType& foo();
};
```

The usage is:

```
MyClass<int> a;
// a.foo(); // error: 'struct MyClass<int>' has no member named 'foo'
MyClass<SpecialType> b;
b.foo();
```